# Increment value with get

Tags: php

I need to **increment** a variable in **one**, and i have this sentence:

```
$obj->setNumber($obj->getNumber()+1);
```

what would be the best way to do it?
I mean, this works but maybe exist something like:

```
$obj->setNumber(++);
```

but this give me an syntax error

Comment: Try `$obj->setNumber(++$obj->getNumber());`

Comment: @mega6382 Thats like the same ;) Definetly not better. But anyway I dont think there is a way to shorten it more.

Comment: Add an *increment method*, then use it like `$obj->incNumber(1);`. (Or *update* if you will)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your obj class you can add:

```
public function increment()
{
    $this->number++;
}
```

And then

```
$obj->increment();
```